# EF Core automatically deleting records on Add Operation

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-3.1

I receive a large JSON having different recordsets in the form of arrays in a Xamarin-Forms application. The recordsets are linked with each other through reference Ids. Basically the data is coming from a relational database and I have to map the data into the device's local SQLite. I am using EFCore for that. I am able to successfully set up the Models and their FKs using OnModelCreating override. I have verified it by logging the table creation scripts. Now the issue is, when I AddRange a list of some records, EF Core automatically deletes some of the records. I don't know why and how.

Here is the screenshot in debugging:

[image]

The data is a huge graph of different relational records. Earlier I was trying to Add the whole graph by saving only the grandparent record. But there are several children who reference the same record more than once. For example, a UserType is referenced by many users. So EF throws Identity tracking issues. Then I decided to not save using the graph, instead save table by table. And now I am facing this issue. To be specific, there is a total of 11 tables involved in my saving. I am able to save 5 tables that have independent data e.g. UserTypes, EntityTypes, ContactTypes, etc. When I came to the 6th table which references some records of 5 saved tables, I am getting this issue.

**Update:**

I solved the problem. The issue was in a relationship that was wrongly defined. A WorkOrder can have one Customer only, but a Customer can be linked to many WorkOrders. I was taking it as One-to-One but was ignoring the other way. I updated the one-to-one to one-to-many in Customer entity and everything started working great!
By the way, this we can say the beauty and perfection of EF Core that it can never allow you to persist data against the rules you have defined. Though automatic deleting was a little confusing but ultimately that was my mistake.

Comment: 1) please try to add code as text, not an image 2) it is not clear from screenshot what type is `WorkOrderHeaders` and `WorkOrder` and how they are related.

Comment: WorkOrder is just a class containing some properties. `pRequest.WorkOrderHeaders` is the data received as a request to store in database; whereas `dbContext.WorkOrder` is the table name in the database. Pretty much self-explanatory I guess for anyone who have ever worked on EF Core.

Comment: I donot know the reason,but `Using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore` and use `SingleInsert`method solve the problem